# How to match the Nth occurrence of a boolean condition?

Tags: pine-script

As per the title, I would like to know if it's possible to target the Nth most recent occurrence of a boolean condition. The use case for this comes up in my planning all the time, yet it eludes me in terms of how to do it.

Examples of some things I might want to be able to target:

"Does something happen twice within N bars?"

Eg (pseudo code using curly braces as means of denoting occurrence):

```
x = conditionA and barssince(conditionA{1}) < 15
```

Or,

"Did a condition happen `between` two occurrences of another condition?"

```
y = conditionA and barssince(conditionA{1}) > conditionB
```

(Note: in this case `1` would mean the 2nd most recent occurrence; ie, `0` would be the most recent)

Here's an example question with a visual:

*"Were there two occurrences of (in my case a higher, then a lower) the blue 'x' shape within 15 bars back from the green 'x'?"*

[image]

Etc.

Since pine is quite series- and condition-/occurrence-oriented, it seems like this would be a fundamental concept (ie, in terms of a built-in function?). Perhaps I am just not aware of it. Admittedly I'm a novice programmer, but that is one of the reasons I love working with Pine - it's novice-friendly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `valuewhen()` function to accomplish this using your condition and `bar_index`. The index runs from 0 as the first historical bar.

So this would give us the bar_index of the most recent occurrence of conditionA :

```
conditionA_index0 = valuewhen(conditionA, bar_index, 0)
```

While this would give the next most recent :

```
conditionA_index1 = valuewhen(conditionA, bar_index, 1)
```

If we also obtain the index of another condition :

```
conditionB_index0 = valuewhen(conditionB, bar_index, 0)
```

Then we can perform a logical comparison to see if the condition occurred in between the last two occurrances of conditionA using the index values that we have obtained :

```
lastB_betweenA = conditionB_index0 > conditionA_index1 and conditionB_index0 < conditionA_index0
```

We can also derive the bars between conditions as well :

```
within_15_bars = conditionA_index0 - conditionA_index1 <= 15
```

If you are doing something more complex, especially if you need to go back a fair number of data points back for your conditions, then it can be better to use a var declared array to store the bar_index values for your conditions.

```
var bool[] conditionA_array = array.new_bool()

if conditionA
     array.unshift(conditionA_array, bar_index)
```

Then you will be able to retrieve the bar_index for nth occurrence of your condition like so :

```
conditionA_index0 = array.get(conditionA_array, 0)
```

Which would retrieve the bar_index of the most recent occurrence of conditionA

Comment: Thank you! This is creative (and a bit confusing at first glance). Just processing it here... In my newbieness I guess I have always thought of a `source` as having a price or an indicator value to it (eg an open/high/low/close, or an RSI level, etc.). So I guess we could say we are in a sense "hacking" the `valuewhen()` function to give us the bar_index number, thereby locating the historical position of the occurrence?

Comment: Yes, something like that. The boolean variables are also series variables just like ohlc values, just instead of having a numeric value it's boolean, eg conditionA[0] was true, conditionA[1] was false, conditionA[2] false, conditionA[3] true, etc. You're using the boolean state of the variable, to obtain the historical "position" or bar_index. So using valuewhen(conditionA, bar_index, 0) is like asking when the last time conditionA was true what was the bar_index?

Comment: Ok. I must be misapplying this somehow, as I can't get a shape to plot. I decided to create another question about usage; since comments aren't the best for details and examples. Perhaps you would like to review. It's at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508343/patterning-condition-occurrences-valuewhen-with-bar-index-as-source