# Patterning condition occurrences valuewhen() with bar_index as source

Tags: pine-script

I am attempting to spot a pattern of conditions (Williams Fractals, in this case).

According to rumpypumpydumpy's [helpful answer/explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486660/how-to-match-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-boolean-condition/69488990?noredirect=1#comment122850165_69488990), I can use the `valuewhen()` function with the `bar_index` variable as the source, giving me the position of the occurrence!

However I must be misapplying this technique, because I can't get a shape to plot.

What I'm looking for is an alternating Fractals pattern (up/down/up); here is my current code snippet:

```
uf_0_bar_index = valuewhen(upFractal, bar_index, 0)
df_0_bar_index = valuewhen(downFractal, bar_index, 0)
uf_1_bar_index = valuewhen(upFractal, bar_index, 1)
df_1_bar_index = valuewhen(downFractal, bar_index, 1)

pattern_order = uf_0_bar_index < df_0_bar_index and df_0_bar_index < uf_1_bar_index
plotshape(pattern_order, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-n, color=color.orange, size = size.small)
```

Eg., this should produce a shape:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
upFractal = high < high[1] and high[1] > high[2]
downFractal = low > low[1] and low[1] < low[2]

plotshape(upFractal, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.abovebar, offset = -1, color = color.green, size = size.normal)
plotshape(downFractal, style = shape.triangledown, location = location.belowbar, offset = -1, color = color.red, size = size.normal)

uf_0_bar_index = valuewhen(upFractal, bar_index, 0)
df_0_bar_index = valuewhen(downFractal, bar_index, 0)
uf_1_bar_index = valuewhen(upFractal, bar_index, 1)
df_1_bar_index = valuewhen(downFractal, bar_index, 1)

pattern_order = uf_0_bar_index > df_0_bar_index and df_0_bar_index > uf_1_bar_index
plotshape(pattern_order, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.abovebar, offset=-1, color=color.orange, size = size.small)
```

Keep in mind the condition for up/down/up will only appear when the last upFractal is confirmed, which in the case of the code above is one bar after the peak of upFractal. If you have defined the fractal with more right bars than one, it will take that number of bars before up/down/up will show.

Comment: Hey ok sorry I'm not following this: 1. Yes my code uses [n] for the fractal length, in accordance with the built-in Williams Fractal variable. 2. Why did you change `uf_0_bar_index < df_0_bar_index` to `uf_0_bar_index > df_0_bar_index`? The last fractal should be an up fractal, so I would think the index should be lower for the `uf_0_bar_index`. Thanks.

Comment: bar_index runs from 0 (the first/oldest historical bar) to the current bar. So for up/down/up we want oldest / next oldest / most recent. So the most recent occurrence of up will have the highest bar_index value, the down will have the second highest bar_index value and the 2nd most recent up will have the lowest bar_index value.

Comment: Oh haha! Since everything else in Pine seems to go from most recent to oldest, I assumed bar_index did too! This is just one of the many cases where it would be nice to able to print values to the console... I still haven't figured out how to work with labels and such, and plotting on an overlay script is just weird. Thanks I will go back and check. =)

Comment: `var label debug_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, style = label.style_label_left), label.set_xy(debug_label, x = bar_index, y = close), label.set_text(debug_label, text = "UP 0 : " + tostring(uf_0_bar_index) + "\nUP 1 : " + tostring(uf_1_bar_index) + "\nDN 0 : " + tostring(df_0_bar_index) + "\nDN 1 : " + tostring(df_1_bar_index))`